# In Swift, how would I split an array of sentences into multiple arrays, separated by a specified beginning and ending sentence?

Tags: arrays, xcode, macos, swift5

I have an array of strings that look somewhat like this:

```
array = ["ID=1", "sentence 1 here", "sentence 2 here", "END", "ID=2", "sentence 1 here", "sentence 2 here", "END"]
```

How could I break up this array into multiple arrays that look like this:

```
array1 = ["ID=1", "sentence 1 here", "sentence 2 here", "END"]
array2 = ["ID=2", "sentence 1 here", "sentence 2 here", "END"]
```

Every answer I've seen so far has only been for integers, and hasn't worked for me, hence why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array’s [split(separator:maxSplits:omittingEmptySubsequences:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017538-split)

Using “END” as a separator will yield *almost* the result you are looking for but it will remove the separator so you need to add it back (eg. using map)

eg.

```swift
let array = ["ID=1", "sentence 1 here", "sentence 2 here", "END", "ID=2", "sentence 1 here", "sentence 2 here", "END"]
let separator = "END"
let newArr = array.split(separator: separator).map {
    $0 + [separator]
}

let array1 = newArr[0]
let array2 = newArr[1]

print(array1)
print(array2)
```

Comment: What you have is an “array of arrays” You can access each array via the indexes.

let array1 = newArr[0]
let array2 = newArr[1]